# All accordions opening at the same time in next app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, accordion

I want the accordion clicked to open up, like show the description it has. But here when I click on one of them, all of them open at the same time. I'm fetching data from a local js File and the data is simply list of objects containing two things - ques and ans

```
const [ show,setShow ] = useState(false)

    return (
        <div className="Faq">

            {
                Faq_Data.map((value, index) => {
                    return(<div className="Faq_Item" key={index}>
                        <div className="Faq_Item_Plate" onClick={()=>setShow(!show)} >
                            <div className="Faq_Item_Button">
                                {value.ques}
                            </div>
                            <img src="/img/critical/plus.png" alt="" />
                        </div>
                        {
                            show && <div className="Faq_Item_Desc">{value.ans}</div>
                        }
                        
                    </div>)
                })
            }


        </div>
```

Comment: The answer linked by Soufiane will only allow expanding one accordion at a time. To expand any number of them, you should create a component for the accordion – and move the `show` hook inside that component. That way, each accordion will have its own `show` state (instead of having one for all of them together, as you do now).

Answer (score 0):

All your accordions are opening because they all use the same `show` value. You'll need individual values for all the different accordions to achieve what you want.

One solution would be to store an array of `boolean`s:

```
// Initialise the state with an array of `false` values,
// each value corresponding to an element of the data array
const [shown, setShown] = useState(Array.from(faqData).fill(false));
return faqData.map(
    // Only do this if you don't have a unique id you could use instead of the index
    // See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
    (faqItem, index) => <div key={index}>
        <button onClick={() => setShown(
            arr => arr.map(
                (tmpShow, tmpIdx) =>
                    index === tmpIdx
                        ? !tmpShow
                        : tmpShow
            )
        )}>
            {faqItem.question}
        </button>
        {shown[i] && <div>{faqItem.answer}</div>}
    </div>
);
```

**But the better, more idiomatic solution** would be to have separate accordion components that accept the question details as `props` and handle their own "open/closed" state. You should also consider using the [`<details>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/details) instead of `<div>`s — both because it's semantically correct here and because it handles the behaviour you seem to be after without any additional coding from you.